# Event Aggregaotr for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need something like EventAggregator in WPF PRISM but for ASP.NET MVC4.

I have following problem. When some action is done, for example commend is added, I need to send 2 mails and SMS message. Now I would like to take it off comment processing action, and to do it somewhere in the background.

One way I could do it is to subscribe to events in Global.asax, and than to execute list of subscribers for specific event when needed (by creating IEventAggregator, using dependency injection, like in PRISM). But then, it will run in same thread as comment processing action.

Is there any other way, and are background tasks and background workers even possible in ASP.NET MVC4?

NOTE: Currently I can't create separate services (WCF for example), which would do that work, because site is running on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

hm, have you hear about signalR (background tasks r possible)? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr